# Insert Into two tables with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im doing a  reservation application and was wondering how would i handle the following scenario; if a booking has 2 or more "extra" items on it how do i create a SP or a trigger even to handle this? the SP i have now works fine for a booking with a single extra item on it. Im i making any sense?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateBooking]

@DateFrom datetime,
@DateTo datetime,
@RoomID int,
@PersonID int,
@ProductID int,
@OrderAmount int


AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO booking(created_on, startdate, enddate, room_id, person_id) 
VALUES (getdate(), @DateFrom, @DateTo, @RoomID, @PersonID)

IF @@error <> 0
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
ELSE

INSERT INTO booking_details (booking_id,prod_id,order_amount) 
VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @ProductID, @OrderAmount)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: can your clarify your question please...Are you asking how to pass a list to stored proc? If so, asked many times before...

Comment: BTW, 'SET NOCOUNT ON;' should be outside the BEGIN TRANSACTION

Comment: @Mitch yeah thats exactly what i was asking for, i just didnt know how to ask for it. i have searched and found the answer now anyway. Thanks - i have the "NOCOUNT" in the right place now too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an xml parameter then loop through it and write them.

> CREATE PROCEDURE
>   SelectByIdList(@productIds xml) AS
>
> DECLARE @Products TABLE (ID int)
>
> INSERT INTO @Products (ID) SELECT
>   ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(20)')
>   FROM @productIds.nodes('/Products/id')
>   as ParamValues(ID)
>
> SELECT * FROM 
>       Products INNER JOIN 
>       @Products p ON    Products.ProductID = p.ID